# How to increment a particular value of a hash table without changing its key?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, hash

I am traversing over an array of numbers (0-9) and want to store there occurrence in hash table with that.

```
int ar[size]={0,2,0,1,4,6,8 ........ 8,6,7}; // array
auto hash=new int[10];   //here the value is initialized to zero

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   //here i want to store the time a number occurred in the array with 
   keys as number itself

  hash[ar[i]] = **valueof(hash[ar[i]])+1** // i want to do this
  }
```

**Edit**

```
auto hash=new int[10]();
```

Comment: The subscript operator returns a **reference** to the value, so you can just increment it! `++hash[ar[i]];` - also, is there any reason you need `hash` to be dynamically allocated? It would probably be easier to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), or perhaps [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if the size can change.

Comment: Did you try doing this: `hash[ar[i]] = hash[ar[i]] + 1;`?

Comment: Afterwards, do you expect a lookup on `valueof(hash[ar[i]])+1` to find anything in the table? If you change the value after your hash of the original value has created then key, then searching for the new value will no longer hash to the correct key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment the value in place:

```
hash[ar[i]]++;
```

Also:

```
// Not true:
auto hash=new int[10];   //here the value is initialized to zero
```

You have to add a initializer:

```
auto hash=new int[10]();   //here the value is initialized to zero
```

Reference:

> If type is an array type, an array of objects is initialized.
>
> - If initializer is absent, each element is default-initialized
> - If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is value-initialized.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Also, the heap allocation is not really needed, you could simply use `int hash[10] = {0}` or `std::array<int, 10> hash; hash.fill(0)`.

Comment: Is that `-` in the array initialisation some trick I am not familiar with, or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line of code:

```
hash[ar[i]] += 1
```